# Windows 2008 R2 VPS resource footprint reduction

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, optimization

Given a Windows 2008 R2 Standard VM with:

- 4x vCPU Intel Xeon E5620
- 1GB RAM
- 15GB HDD

What can I do to reduce the amount of CPU/RAM/HDD utilised by the OS?

- The VM will be used exclusively as a web server, so all other functions can be considered non-essential
- Server Core is not an option as I need to be able to use certain tools that do not have good command-line equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Don't install any unneccessary software and disable all unneccessary services, based on the roles and/or features installed on the server.